# Отслеживание события в Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю angular 2. Имеется массив символов. Если символ является "," нужно дождаться введенного значения и по нажатию клавиши enter продолжить выполнение. как дождаться ввода и вернуться к выполнению кода в этом же месте? спасибо

```html
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'code_input',
    template: `<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Input</h4>
    <input type="text">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment" (keyup)="outcode(inputCode)"
              [(ngModel)]="inputCode"></textarea>
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div>{{ outputCode }}</div>
                </div>`,
    styles: [`
        :host {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    
}
    `],
    styleUrls: ['bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css', 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css']
})
export class CodeInput {
    @Input() inputCode: string;
    outputCode: string;



    outcode(inputCode: string) {

        var acc: string[];
        acc = inputCode.split('');
        var cpu = new Array(30000).fill(0);

        var brc: number = 0;

        var j: number = 0;
        this.outputCode = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            if(acc[i] === '>') {  j++; }
            if(acc[i] === '<') {  j--; }
            if(acc[i] === '+') {cpu[j]++;}
            if(acc[i] === '-') {cpu[j]--;}
            if(acc[i] === '.') {this.outputCode += String.fromCharCode(cpu[j]);}
            if(acc[i] === ',') {
                   //дождаться ввода нужно здесь
            }
            if(acc[i] === '[')
            {
                if(!cpu[j])
                {
                    ++brc;
                    while(brc)
                    {
                        ++i;
                        if (acc[i] == '[') {++brc;}
                        if (acc[i] == ']') {--brc;}
                    }
                }else continue;
            }
            else if(acc[i] == ']')
            {
                if(!cpu[j])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(acc[i] == ']') {
                        brc++;
                    }
                    while(brc)
                    {
                        --i;
                        if(acc[i] == '[') {brc--;}
                        if(acc[i] == ']') {brc++;}
                    }
                    --i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```